# script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-cgi

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have just seen a new series  of error in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

> [Thu Oct 31 06:59:04 2013] [error] [client 203.197.197.18] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php
>
> [Thu Oct 31 06:59:08 2013] [error] [client 203.197.197.18] script not
>   found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5
>
> [Thu Oct 31 06:59:09 2013] [error] [client 203.197.197.18] script not
>   found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-cgi
>
> [Thu Oct 31 06:59:14 2013] [error] [client 203.197.197.18] script not
>   found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php.cgi
>
> [Thu Oct 31 06:59:14 2013] [error] [client 203.197.197.18] script not
>   found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php4

This server is running Ubuntu 12.04lts.

I have never seen this sort of attack before, should i be concerned or securing my system in any way for them?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're running a default configuration of Apache on Ubuntu (or have used the default config as a blind template for other virtualhost directives) you'll likely find that you have a ScriptAlias directive mapping /cgi-bin/ (relative to the apache document root) to the filesystem location of /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ - so what they're actually trying to load is http://your.host.name/cgi-bin/php4.

If you're not using your cgi-bin for anything, you're unlikely to lose anything you care about by commenting out the sections relating to it (and the more defined to your needs your configuration is, the smaller any potential attack surface).

You'll find the relevant directives for the default site in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default, if memory serves.

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.10's default apache config, I found the `ScriptAlias` directive hiding in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Seems theres someone trying to find a php cgi binary in your cgi-bin path. As long as there's nothing exploitable in there, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: But with apache running are they effectively attempting to access WEBROOT/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php4   ?

Comment: see Phil's reply, the default ScriptAlias directive is responsible for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the default server cgi-bin like so:

```
a2disconf serve-cgi-bin
systemctl reload apache2
```